# NGINX downloads php file

Tags: php, nginx

I have my own MVC that houses a bunch of apps with this folder structure:

- Main Project

  - Index.php
  - Model (directory)
  - View (directory)
  - Controller (directory)
  - Sub Project 1 (directory)

    - Index.php
    - Model (directory)
    - View (directory)
    - Controller (directory)
  - Sub Project 2 (directory)

    - Index.php
    - Model (directory)
    - View (directory)
    - Controller (directory)

everything works fine with apache. I want to try it using  Nginx but when I access it on my browser it downloads the index.php it does not execute it.

This is my setup on nginx:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 break; }
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two lines:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 break; }
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

Are attempting to perform the same function. If a file does not exist, try `/index.php`.

The first line is failing because of the `break`, which attempts to process `/index.php` in the `location /` block rather than the `location ~ \.php$` block.

To correct the first line, `last` should be used instead of `break`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

But if you include the `try_files` line, you do not need the `if ... rewrite` statement. The following performs a similar function:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$uri&$args;
```

I prefer the `try_files` approach, but either should work, but you do not need both. `try_files` is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). Note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of the `if` block.

Also, note some problems with your `location ~ \.php$` block:

- you are missing a back-slash in your regex
- the `try_files` directive should end with a URI or an =404 - not both

Comment: Thanks for clearing that info about break and last.
I tried to rewrite .htaccess file to the rewrite of nginx.
Last problem is when I call this url. http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mainproject/ index.php fires it correctly redirects to my login http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mainproject/login/ but the response is Internal server error it does not get index.php of the main project that should call the appropriate controllers.

Comment: Internal server error means look at the logfiles. If you get stuck again, post a new question. Happy debugging!